# VPN Router question

Tags: vpn, router

What does it take to set up a wireless router to connect to a vpn service so everybody in the local wireless network surfs the internet through that vpn tunnel? What do I need to be careful about?

I'm willing to spend 200-300 on the router and VPN service, but I want to make sure I don't run into compatibility issues such as a router not using a certain protocol.

Any router or vpn service suggestions are greatly welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good number of SOHO NAT router will support connecting through a PPTP configuration. Setting up a PPTP configuration between the NAT router and a PPTP server should yield what you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're better off acquiring a WRT54GS for most likely less than $40 and putting DD-WRT on it, or maybe a new router with DD-WRT which has very good PPTP support. If you're only going to use PPTP. DD-WRT also works with OpenVPN and I'm sure with a bit of work you can adapt it to other protocols. I use DD-WRT as a Wireless Access Point connected through VPN to my Win 2008 R2 server whose DHCP server assigns IP addresses to all the wireless clients connected through DD-WRT.